# Remove white space characters from a char[] array in D

Tags: d, dmd, phobos

What is the recomended way to remove white space from a char[] in D. for example using dmd 2.057 I have,

```
import std.stdio;
import std.string; 
import std.algorithm;

char[] line;

int main(){
  line = r"this is a     line with spaces   "; 
  line = removechars(line," "); 
  writeln(line);
  return 0;
}
```

On compile, this will generate this error:

```
Error: cannot implicitly convert expression ("this is a     line with spaces   ") of type string to char[]
    Error: template std.string.removechars(S) if (isSomeString!(S)) does not match any function template declaration
    Error: template std.string.removechars(S) if (isSomeString!(S)) cannot deduce template function from argument types !()(char[],string)
```

On doing some google search, i find that a similar error had been reported as a [bug and had been filed](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/bugs/Issue_6191_New_removechars_doesn_t_accept_a_const_string_30931.html) in june 2011, but not sure whether it was was referring to the same thing or a different issue.

In general, what is the approach recommended to remove certain characters from a string and maintating the order of characters from the previous array of chars?

In this case return

```
assert(line == "thisisalinewithspaces")
```

after removing whitespace characters

Comment: Does changing `line = r"this is a     line with spaces   ";` to `line = r"this is a     line with spaces   ".dup;` help?

Comment: no it does not. It only eliminates the first error on type conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

removechars accepts all string types (char[], wchar[], dchar[], string, wstring and dstring), but the second argument has to be the same type as the first. So if you pass a char[] as first arg, the second arg also has to be a char[]. You are, however, passing a string: " "

A simple solution would be to duplicate the string to a char[]: " ".dup

> removechars(line, " ".dup)

This also works:

> removechars(line, ['\x20'])

Comment: That answers the question of what's going on here for me too :).  I took a quick look at the source for `removechars` and couldn't tell why it wouldn't work as he had written.

Answer (score 3):

Give `removechars` an `immutable(char)[]` (which is what `string` is aliased to).  You'll also need to `.dup` the result of `removechars` to get a mutable char array.

```cpp
import std.stdio;
import std.string; 
import std.algorithm;

char[] line;

void main()
{
    auto str = r"this is a     line with spaces   "; 
    line = removechars(str," ").dup; 
    writeln(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I try all but can't. Now I can.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void main(){
char pswd[10]="XOXO     ";//this actually after i fetch from oracle
string pass="";
char passwd[10]="";
pass=pswd;
int x = pass.size(), y=0;
while(y<x)
{
if(pass[y]!=' ')
{passwd[y]=pass[y];}
y++;
}
strcpy(pswd,passwd);
cout<<pswd;
}
```